# How to sum restricted columns in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Suppose we are having below dataframe:

```
Name     Filter_1  Filter_2   Weight
Rat       A          1          1
Cat       B          2          10
Lion      A          3          80
Tiger     C          4          60
Dog       A          1          20
```

I want to sum the weight of Animals which having Filter_1 as 'A' & Filter_2 as '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df[(df['Filter_1']=='A') & (df['Filter_2']==1)]['Weight'].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
df.loc[(df['Filter_1']==A)&(df['Filter_2']==1), 'Weight'].sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This also will work:

```
df[df.Filter_1 == 'A'][df.Filter_2 == 1].sum()
```